# Symfony 2: Change inner custom forms fields options

Tags: symfony

In my action, I have this:

```
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($myEntity);

$formBuilder
    // (...)
    ->add('myInnerEntities', 'collection', array(
            'label' => 'My inner entities',
            'type'   => new InnerEntityType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'options' => [
                    'InnerEntityTypeField1' => [
                        'label' => 'Change this image'
                    ],
                    'InnerEntityTypeField2' => [
                        'label' => 'Change the caption'
                    ]
                ]
        ))
```

In the 'options' of the collection of InnerEntityType, I'm trying to override the options of the fields of each InnerEntityType in the collection.

The above code doesn't work. How could I achieve that, with of course avoiding to create several InnerEntityType classes with different label (or other options) values ?

Comment: are you displaying elements in twig .?
with form.entity.vars.prototype..?

Comment: @Jd patel yes, the collection can grow or shrink depending on user input...

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="tags" data-prototype="{% filter escape %}{% include 'yourBundle:formviewfolder:prototype.html.twig' with {'form': form.collectionname.vars.prototype} %}{% endfilter %}">

                                                {{ form_errors(form.collectionname) }}
                                                {{ form_widget(form.collectionname) }}

             </ul>
```

create one prototype.html.twig in main form view folder as following

//prototype.html.twig

```
<div >

    {{ form_row(form.InnerEntityTypeField1,{'label':'your label'}) }}

</div>
<div >

    {{ form_row(form.InnerEntityTypeField2,{'label':'your label'}) }}

</div>
```